# Partial download trouble with Node.js filestreams: writes ~400 bytes of 100 kB image file and moves on without any error

Tags: javascript, node.js

While trying to learn to use Node filestreams, I wrote a few test apps that fetched images from remote servers and saved them to disk. Problem is, while some of the test images downloaded fine, others failed in a bizarre way without returning errors and writing only 400 to 460 bytes of 100+ kB images. Here you can see nautilus showing a successful download on the left and a failed partial download that never threw any errors on the right. The partial downloads are always in the 400 to 460 byte range.

[image: successfull download on the left, partial download on the right]

Here's the sample code I'm using for my tests; some images downloaded fine, others download partially and throw no errors:

```
var 
    express = require( 'express' )
,   app     = express.createServer()
,   request = require( 'request' )
,   fs      = require( 'fs' )
,   url     = 'http://static.designspiration.net/data/assets/012311-010912AM_158289.jpg';

app.get( '/', function( req, res){
    request( url, function( err ){
        if( err ){ console.log( err ); }
    }).pipe( fs.createWriteStream( './Downloads/testimage.jpg' ) );
});

app.listen( 8083 );
```

Anyone have any clue what's going on?

Comment: Is it consistently the same files that fail, or just random?

Comment: I triple-checked a few files and they consistently failed. That's why I threw in a static URL in the sample; it's one of the many that consistently gave me trouble.

Comment: Ah okay, that's why I asked :P Your sample code worked fine on my machine... I'd recommend debugging by replacing your pipe call with binding 'data' directly, then see how much data is being emitted. At least them you'll know if it is the request or the file side of things that's not working.

Comment: I tried again this morning and the URL in the sample code works now. The thumbnail still doesn't show up, so there seems to be some bytes missing; the image opens fine. But the "partial download" mystery still continues with other images. _"binding 'data' directly, then see how much data is being emitted."_ — I'm not very familiar with this but I'll try swapping the `pipe` approach with one where I can get a low level look at how things work. Thanks for the tip.